# How can I cause violations of normality on an ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova

Here I leave a code (along with the needed libraries) to observe an ANOVA under conditions of normality.

As you can see, I included `x1` and `x2`, which were tampered for the purpose of creating violations of normality; the reason for this is to find how power is affected by lack of normality.

```
library(pwr)
library(psych)
library(ggplot2)
n <-1000
SampleLesserLimit=20
SampleUpperLimit=150
m <- seq(from=SampleLesserLimit, to=SampleUpperLimit)
pwr<-matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 0)
p_anova<-matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 0)
for(i in m){
  for(j in 1:n){
    x1 <- rnorm(i, 1, 1) + rnorm(10, 0, 2) + c(1, rep(NA, 18), 1)
    x2 <- rnorm(i, 0.5, 1) + rnorm(10, 0, 2) + c(1, rep(NA, 18), 1)
  }
  print(i)
  print((pwr.anova.test(k=2, n=i, f=.5, sig.level=.05)$power))
  p_anova <- rbind(p_anova, c("Number of Cases"=i, "Power"=((pwr.anova.test(k=2, n=i, f=.5, sig.level=.05)$power))))
}
plot(p_anova, xlim = c(20, 150), ylim = c(0, 1), main = "Power on a two-groups ANOVA", type="l")
```

I expected the result to be a moderate/low power, yet the results are the same as the ones obtained without adding `x1` or `x2`. Is there anything this code lacks and is needed in order to obtain results without normality being met? Is there any other way to cause violations of normality, such as with Pearson's correlation?

Comment: I don't understand your code generating the x1 and x2. Also... You never use them do I don't know why you would think they impact power?

Comment: In addition to not using `x1` and `x2` in the anova, the code to generate `x1` and `x2` probably isn't doing what you intend. For example, run `rnorm(20, 1, 1) + rnorm(10, 0, 2) + c(1, rep(NA, 18), 1)` and see what you get. I'm not positive, but maybe `rnorm(20, 1, 1) + rnorm(10, 0, 2) + c(1, rep(0, 18), 1)` gives what you were intending?